# How can I stop Mendeley's automatic synchronization？

Tags: mendeley

How can I stop Mendeley's automatic synchronization？ I do not want to upload some pdf files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming. It seems to fit SuperUser.

Answer (score 12):

You can prevent Mendeley from syncing all of your pdf or that in particular folders of your library. Just select "All Documents" and then click "Edit Settings"

[How to open Mendeley Sync Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS8T9.jpg)

Then you can opt out "Synchronize attached files" or select what folders do you want to sync.

Comment: Edit Settings is disabled. Now my library is completely broken, with duplicate PDFs, missing PDF links, missing files that were painstakingly added one by one for years.

Comment: Also when you add new document and restart mendeley new documents are synced to web. I canot find a way do completely disable sync.

Comment: The answer is technically correct, you can manually disable sync for all the documents in your Mendeley library by going to tab (selecting) "All Documents" and clicking "Edit Settings". However, the "Edit Settings" does not edit the settings of the documents that are and will be listed in tab "All Documents", it only applies the settings to the current documents, and I have found no way to edit the default syncing settings for new documents.

That means you have to manually set each new file you add to "don't sync file".

Comment: Additionally, if you disable the syncing of the files to the cloud of Mendeley, your files will not be removed from the library/cloud of Mendeley, if you also want them out of there, you have to open the browser and manually remove the files from there too.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your internet and edit `settings`. It will be enabled.